# Set SelectionState for entity when clicked

Tags: draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I have a case where I can click on an entity, and then select new content to replace the entire entity. For example:

```
Here is some text [special entity] and some more text
                       ^ click anywhere inside the brackets
```

After choosing new content, it replaces the old entity text and becomes:

```
Here is some text [my new entity] and some more text
```

Basically, I'm trying to do:

```
const newSelectionState = SelectionState.createEmpty(key).merge({
  anchorOffset: entityStart,
  focusOffset: entityEnd
});
```

I've tried using `currentContentState.getSelectionBefore(key).getStartOffset()` and `currentContentState.getSelectionAfter(key).getStartOffset()` but the values seem unreliable.

How should I get the proper start and end offsets for the entity? Or, is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found a library called [draftjs-utils](https://github.com/jpuri/draftjs-utils) that has a method called `getEntityRange` and this is able to give me the start and end offsets I need.